# Audacity Recorded Commentary Is Out Of Sync With My Webcam And Gameplay Recordings

Tags: audio, audacity, gameaudio

so basically my commentary that i recorded for a game play video is out of sync with my webcam footage and my gameplay footage

Webcam: Logitech C922 Pro Stream Webcam

My Microphone: Stadium USBMIC1 (you can only get this microphone in australia)

Laptop Specs:

Cpu: Amd radeon a6-7310 with radeon r4 graphics

Graphics: amd radeon r5m330

My Laptop Specs According To Piriform Speccy:

Operating System
Windows 10 Home 64-bit
CPU
AMD K16 
Carrizo-L 28nm Technology
RAM
8.00GB Single-Channel DDR3 @ 798MHz (11-11-12-28)
Motherboard
FF50 06F7 (Socket FP4)
Graphics
Generic PnP Monitor (1366x768@60Hz)
1024MB ATI AMD Radeon R4 Graphics (Toshiba) 
2048MB ATI AMD Radeon R5 M330 (Toshiba) 
CrossFire Disabled
Storage
931GB TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100 (SATA) 
Optical Drives
HL-DT-ST DVDRAM GUB0N
Audio
Realtek High Definition Audio

The webcam and gameplay footage have been trancoded into a constant frame rate with handbrake,

i do suspect that handbrake is converting my video files to constant but its not converting the audio in those video files to constant

the commentary is exported from audacity after it has been edited

```
MediaInfo Results:

-Converted With Handbrake

 -Gameplay Footage:

 General

Complete name : C:\Users\nicholasj\Desktop\Nicholas Josey-The Diamond Block\Resources & Files\_Resources\Re-Transcoded Videos\Turbo Dismount Ep01 VEF.mp4

Format : MPEG-4
Format profile : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID : mp42 (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size : 520 MiB
Duration : 26 min 26 s
Overall bit rate mode : Variable
Overall bit rate : 2 747 kb/s
Encoded date : UTC 2018-06-28 15:52:39
Tagged date : UTC 2018-06-28 15:52:39
Writing application : HandBrake 1.1.1 2018061800

Video
ID : 1
Format : AVC
Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile : High@L3.1
Format settings : 3 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC : No
Format settings, RefFrames : 3 frames
Format settings, GOP : M=1, N=8
Codec ID : avc1
Codec ID/Info : Advanced Video Coding
Duration : 26 min 26 s
Bit rate : 2 591 kb/s
Width : 800 pixels
Height : 600 pixels
Display aspect ratio : 4:3
Frame rate mode : Constant
Frame rate : 30.000 FPS
Color space : YUV
Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0
Bit depth : 8 bits
Scan type : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame) : 0.180
Stream size : 490 MiB (94%)
Writing library : x264 core 155 r2901 7d0ff22
Encoding settings : cabac=0 / ref=3 / deblock=0:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=6 / lookahead_threads=1 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=0 / weightp=0 / keyint=8 / keyint_min=5 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=8 / rc=2pass / mbtree=1 / bitrate=2591 / ratetol=1.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / cplxblur=20.0 / qblur=0.5 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Encoded date : UTC 2018-06-28 15:52:39
Tagged date : UTC 2018-06-28 15:52:39
Color range : Limited
Color primaries : BT.709
Transfer characteristics : BT.709
Matrix coefficients : BT.709

Audio
ID : 2
Format : AAC
Format/Info : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile : LC
Codec ID : mp4a-40-2
Duration : 26 min 26 s
Bit rate mode : Variable
Bit rate : 153 kb/s
Channel(s) : 2 channels
Channel(s)_Original : 1 channel
Channel positions : Front: C
Sampling rate : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode : Lossy
Stream size : 28.9 MiB (6%)
Title : Mono / Mono
Default : Yes
Alternate group : 1
Encoded date : UTC 2018-06-28 15:52:39
Tagged date : UTC 2018-06-28 15:52:39

Webcam Footage:

General
Complete name : C:\Users\nicholasj\Desktop\Nicholas Josey-The Diamond Block\Resources & Files\_Resources\Re-Transcoded Videos\Turbo Dismount Ep01_Facecam VEF.m4v
Format : MPEG-4
Format profile : Base Media / Version 2
Codec ID : mp42 (isom/iso2/avc1/mp41)
File size : 525 MiB
Duration : 26 min 34 s
Overall bit rate mode : Variable
Overall bit rate : 2 760 kb/s
Encoded date : UTC 2018-06-29 07:24:52
Tagged date : UTC 2018-06-29 07:24:52
Writing application : HandBrake 1.1.1 2018061800

Video
ID : 1
Format : AVC
Format/Info : Advanced Video Codec
Format profile : High@L3.1
Format settings : 3 Ref Frames
Format settings, CABAC : No
Format settings, RefFrames : 3 frames
Format settings, GOP : M=1, N=8
Codec ID : avc1
Codec ID/Info : Advanced Video Coding
Duration : 26 min 34 s
Bit rate : 2 594 kb/s
Width : 1 280 pixels
Height : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio : 16:9
Frame rate mode : Constant
Frame rate : 30.000 FPS
Color space : YUV
Chroma subsampling : 4:2:0
Bit depth : 8 bits
Scan type : Progressive
Bits/(Pixel*Frame) : 0.094
Stream size : 493 MiB (94%)
Writing library : x264 core 155 r2901 7d0ff22
Encoding settings : cabac=0 / ref=3 / deblock=0:0:0 / analyse=0x3:0x113 / me=hex / subme=7 / psy=1 / psy_rd=1.00:0.00 / mixed_ref=1 / me_range=16 / chroma_me=1 / trellis=1 / 8x8dct=1 / cqm=0 / deadzone=21,11 / fast_pskip=1 / chroma_qp_offset=-2 / threads=6 / lookahead_threads=1 / sliced_threads=0 / nr=0 / decimate=1 / interlaced=0 / bluray_compat=0 / constrained_intra=0 / bframes=0 / weightp=0 / keyint=8 / keyint_min=5 / scenecut=40 / intra_refresh=0 / rc_lookahead=8 / rc=crf / mbtree=1 / crf=20.0 / qcomp=0.60 / qpmin=0 / qpmax=69 / qpstep=4 / ip_ratio=1.40 / aq=1:1.00
Encoded date : UTC 2018-06-29 07:24:52
Tagged date : UTC 2018-06-29 07:24:52
Color range : Limited
Color primaries : BT.709
Transfer characteristics : BT.709
Matrix coefficients : BT.709

Audio
ID : 2
Format : AAC
Format/Info : Advanced Audio Codec
Format profile : LC
Codec ID : mp4a-40-2
Duration : 26 min 33 s
Bit rate mode : Variable
Bit rate : 161 kb/s
Channel(s) : 2 channels
Channel(s)_Original : 1 channel
Channel positions : Front: C
Sampling rate : 48.0 kHz
Frame rate : 46.875 FPS (1024 SPF)
Compression mode : Lossy
Stream size : 30.6 MiB (6%)
Title : Mono / Mono
Language : English
Default : Yes
Alternate group : 1
Encoded date : UTC 2018-06-29 07:24:52
Tagged date : UTC 2018-06-29 07:24:52

MediaInfo Results (Commentary  Recorded In Audacity, Not Converted With Handbrake):

General

Complete name : C:\Users\nicholasj\Desktop\Nicholas Josey-The Diamond Block\Resources & Files\_Resources\Audacity Saves And Exports\Turbo Dismount Ep01 Commentary 153K.wav
Format : Wave
File size : 137 MiB
Duration : 24 min 55 s
Overall bit rate mode : Constant
Overall bit rate : 768 kb/s
Writing application : Lavf55.33.100

Audio
Format : PCM
Format settings : Little / Signed
Codec ID : 1
Duration : 24 min 55 s
Bit rate mode : Constant
Bit rate : 768 kb/s
Channel(s) : 1 channel
Sampling rate : 48.0 kHz
Bit depth : 16 bits
Stream size : 137 MiB (100%)

MediaInfo Results (Original Files):

Gameplay Footage:

General
Complete name : C:\Users\nicholasj\Desktop\Nicholas Josey-The Diamond Block\A-Fraps Screen Recordings\TurboDismount 2018-06-27 15-40-08-39.avi
Format : AVI
Format/Info : Audio Video Interleave
Format profile : OpenDML
File size : 7.29 GiB
Duration : 26 min 26 s
Overall bit rate : 39.5 Mb/s

Video
ID : 0
Format : Fraps
Codec ID : FPS1
Duration : 26 min 26 s
Bit rate : 37.9 Mb/s
Width : 800 pixels
Height : 600 pixels
Display aspect ratio : 4:3
Frame rate : 30.000 FPS
Color space : YUV
Bit depth : 8 bits
Bits/(Pixel*Frame) : 2.635
Stream size : 7.01 GiB (96%)

Audio
ID : 1
Format : PCM
Format settings : Little / Signed
Codec ID : 1
Duration : 26 min 26 s
Bit rate mode : Constant
Bit rate : 1 536 kb/s
Channel(s) : 2 channels
Sampling rate : 48.0 kHz
Bit depth : 16 bits
Stream size : 290 MiB (4%)
Alignment : Aligned on interleaves
Interleave, duration : 1000 ms (29.99 video frames)

Webcam Footage:

General
Complete name : C:\Users\nicholasj\Desktop\Nicholas Josey-The Diamond Block\Resources & Files\_Resources\Unedited WebCam Recordings\Logitech Webcam Software Recorded Facecam\Video 34.wmv
Format : Windows Media
File size : 105 MiB
Duration : 26 min 34 s
Overall bit rate mode : Variable
Overall bit rate : 555 kb/s
Maximum Overall bit rate : 3 275 kb/s
Encoded date : UTC 2018-06-28 13:28:20.812

Video
ID : 2
Format : WMV2
Codec ID : WMV2
Codec ID/Info : Windows Media Video 8
Description of the codec : Windows Media Video V8
Duration : 26 min 34 s
Bit rate mode : Variable
Bit rate : 1 592 kb/s
Width : 1 280 pixels
Height : 720 pixels
Display aspect ratio : 16:9
Frame rate : 10.000 FPS
Nominal frame rate : 15.000 FPS
Bit depth : 8 bits
Bits/(Pixel*Frame) : 0.173
Stream size : 303 MiB
Language : English (AU)
NumberOfFrames : 7970

Audio
ID : 1
Format : WMA
Format version : Version 2
Codec ID : 161
Codec ID/Info : Windows Media Audio
Description of the codec : Windows Media Audio 9.2 - 20 kbps, 32 kHz, mono (A/V) 1-pass CBR
Duration : 26 min 34 s
Bit rate mode : Constant
Bit rate : 1 411 kb/s
Channel(s) : 1 channel
Sampling rate : 32.0 kHz
Bit depth : 16 bits
Stream size : 268 MiB
Language : English (AU)
NumberOfFrames : 4986
```

i have also created forum threads on the forum of my video editing softwares website and the handbrake support forum

Comment: To clarify, do you just need to shift the timestamp on the audio to line up with the video? Or is the audio actually a different length to the video?

Comment: the audio is actually a different length to the video even after converting my gameplay & webcam recordings to constant in handbrake

Comment: Why are you using HandBrake? did you try to use a different video editor to add your commentary to the video? Most people just use HandBrake for ripping DVDs

Comment: i did not use handbrake to add the commentary to the video, i use a seperate video editor for that

Comment: i only convert the GAMEPLAY RECORDING & THE WEBCAM RECORDING to constant in handbrake and i ONLY EXPORT the recorded audacity commentary from audacity itself no conversion is done what so ever to the actual commentary that i record with audacity

Comment: This Is My Workflow If It Will Help In Any Way: [Record Game With Fraps, Record Webcam With Logitech Webcam Software And Record Commentary In Audacity At The Same Time] > [Save Audacity Commentary & Edit It] > [Export Final Audacity Commentary For Video Editor] > [Convert/Transcode Recorded Webcam & Game Footage In Handbrake To Constant Frame Rate] > [Import All FIles Into Video Editor (Hitfilm Express)(Latest Version) For Editing] > [Create & Export Thumbnail With Gimp] > [Upload To Youtube]

Comment: The video probably has SMPTE drop time timing information in it while the audio is assuming non-drop or something like that, and you’ll need to set up your video editing software to reconcile that. If the audio file is longer than the video, this is a likely cause.

Comment: What happens if you skip the handbrake step? I don’t understand why you’re using handbrake at all. Can the video editor import the video and audio without doing anything in handbrake?

Comment: Todd Wilcox i need to convert the webcam footage & gameplay footage i handbrake as the gameplay footage is recorded with fraps and fraps uses its own proprietary format and the webcam footage recorded by logitech webcam software is unusable as it is originally recorded in 15 fps and i cat change that